# django escape tag not escaping single quotation marks

Tags: django, django-templates, escaping

I am using django 1.7.

When a user enters single and/or double quotation marks as part of their input, the form displaying their entered data is broken.

So I used django's [escape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#escape) tag, which should deal with this very easily.

However, the [escape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#escape) tag is only escaping the double quotation marks. The single quotation marks are not being escaped and are breaking the test form.

Here is an example of my code:

```
{{ field|escape }}
```

Does anyone know how to overcome this issue.

**EDIT**

Here is my form field template code (form_fields.html):

```
<div id="row_{{ field.auto_id }}" class="form-group {% if field.errors %}error{% endif %} {% if hide_row %}hidden{% endif %}">
    <label for="{{ field.auto_id }}" class="control-label {{ field.css_classes }}">
        {{ field.label }}{% if field.label %}:{% endif %}
    </label>
    <div class="controls {{ control_classes }}">
        {{ field|escape }}
        {% if field.errors %}
            <span class="help-inline">
                <strong>
                    {% for e in field.errors %}
                        {{ e }}<br/>
                    {% endfor %}
                </strong>
            </span>
        {% endif %}
        {% if field.help_text %}
            <p class="help-block">
                {{ field.help_text }}
            </p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the form template field code:

```
{% load form_fields %}
....
{% form_field form.name_details_prefix_title %}
```

Comment: Can you provide some example? your form, fields and some template code to re-create that?

Comment: GwybBleidD - added code as requested.

Comment: You can't escpe whole field using `escape` filter, you should only do it with value, but that should be working automaticaly. Please show your form class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ultimately tracked th error to a js issue.

I used the following tag to solve the issue:

```
{{ field|escapejs }}
```

Hope that this helps some one.

Comment: Helped me a lot. was struggling with a single quote. Thanks a lot